# Async loading inside cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asynchronous

It it possible to use Task (System.Threading) inside Razor??

What i'm trying to do is this: I have a table that I want to async fill.

Look at the code:

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> preenche =
        @<text>
            <tr><td>oi1</td><td>oi2</td></tr>
        </text>;
}

...
<tbody>
    @Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach(Apontamento ap in Model.apontamentos)
            {
                preenche(ap);
            }
        })
</tbody>
```

The output is just this: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`

Is it possible? Or I can just have what i'm trying to do using Ajax?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the page to render and appear instantly and then have something happen later on (say an operation takes 5 seconds to complete) then you can get the page to update when the data is available by doing something like this (More information about [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)).

On your **Razor view** you can add some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('LongRunningAsyncTask', function (result) 
    {
        // Populate table or other actions with: result.Data
        // ...
    });
</script>
```

Then in your **Controller** you would have the tasks like this:

```
public JsonResult LongRunningAsyncTask()
{
    // Show this is async and won't render straight away...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // Build up our view model
    var viewModel = new TestViewModel();

    // Send back as a Json result
    var result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = viewModel;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT do this in the View. Make asynchronous action but when you start rendering the view all the data should be ready.

Comment: this isn't an answer, also I can think of UI scenarios where loading more data after page load would be ideal and would create a snappier interface

Comment: It was not clear if the OP wanted to use asynchronous server processing or AJAX call so it is entirely possible that I am answering another question. However I don't see how the rest of your comment relates to my answer. I am pointing out that if you do asynchronous processing on the server you do it in the controller not in the view. What is more async operations in web scenarios aim to reduce server load and increase scalability and not to create snappier interfaces.